# Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: how to allow only certain domains?

Tags: security, iframe, iframe-app, cross-origin-embedder-policy, cross-origin-opener-policy

on a website I have to embed an iframe that requires the following headers on my website, since it needs the SharedArrayBuffer feature:

```
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
```

Unfortunately, a 3rd party service IFRAME I still need in my page is not loading anymore.
There's a way to allow a 3rd party domain even with the embedded-policy turned on?

Thanks.
Dario.

Comment: did you get an answer to this? does the accepted answer work for you? seems like COOP/COEP shouldn't have anything to do with frame ancestors, but does that solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd party website will have to add your domain in the content security policy response header:

Response header from 3rd party website:

```
"Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.yourdomain.com;";
```

If you don't have control over it, there is nothing you can do.

Comment: Thanks! I cannot verify this since I don't have control on 3rd party service, but it goes on what I was thinking!

Answer (score 3):

If the document loaded into iframe is cross-origin, it needs to send the following two headers:

```
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin
```

If it's difficult, please [register for an origin trial](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/enabling-shared-array-buffer/#origin-trial) to temporarily exempt the requirement from your domain. This will let your website use SharedArrayBuffer without COOP/COEP headers at least on Chrome.

In the meantime, the standard body is working to introduce an option to load iframe without requiring those headers. Learn more at:

https://github.com/camillelamy/explainers/blob/master/anonymous_iframes.md

Answer (score -1):

You need control over the domain you want to embed to remove/amend its CORS policy. It the domain has explicitely blocked Cross-Origin requests, there's nothing you can do about it.

This is used to avoid anyone hijacking any site you want (you could have a full screen Google in an iframe running with your ads on top on bettergoogle.com, things like that).
[This will help out read this one](https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-cors-18ad6b478e2b)